# Does the background positioning interface for Android 10 and above support continuous location information acquisition?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Because Android models of Android 10 and above restrict the third-party background to continuously obtain location information, if we use Huawei's own SDK positioning interface, can we ask whether we run the positioning interface in the background to obtain location information while the phone is sleeping. If the mobile phone is in the sleep state, the current location information is obtained at intervals of 5 minutes to achieve the effect of tracking or tracing the location of the mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huawei's positioning SDK supports continuous acquisition of location information, you can refer to this document for development https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/development/HMS-Guides/location-guidev4#h1-1576578169417-0